# How do I prove that the equation $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{4}\cos(x)\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(y)dy$ has a unique solution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functional-equations

I have found the solution $f(x) = x + \frac{\pi^2}{24}\cos(x)$, but I need to prove that it is the only one.

I have tried assuming that there are two solutions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and then subtracting them and trying to find a limit that goes to $0$, but I've been unsuccesful.

\begin{equation}
   |f(x)-g(x)| = \frac{1}{4}|\cos(x)\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(y)-g(y)dy|
\end{equation}
How do I continue from here?

Edit: I'm searching in $L^2((0, \pi/2))$

Comment: In which space are you looking for solutions?

Comment: Rewrite your problem as $f(x) = x+a\cos(x)$ and $a = \frac 14 \int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\text dx$. Plug the first equation in the second one to obtain an equation on $a$.

Comment: @Gary Yeah, you're right. I'm searching in $L^2((0, \pi/2))$.

Comment: Then use Banach fixed-point theorem.

Comment: @Gary could you elaborate further?

Comment: @Gary The integral term does not depend on $x$, so this is not really an integral/functional equation. No need to use such a strong theorem.

Comment: @SolubleFish And how would I prove that it is unique doing it that way?

Comment: @Gary how do I show that it is a mapping?

Comment: You define $T: L^2 \to L^2$ by letting $Tf(x)$ to be the right-hand sie of your equation. Then $T$ is a contraction since by the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality $$
\left\|Tf(x)-Tg(x)\right\|_2^2  =\int_0^{\pi /2} {\left| {\frac{1}{4}\cos (x)\int_0^{\pi /2} {(f(y) - g(y))dy} } \right|^2 dx}  = \int_0^{\pi /2} {\left| {\frac{1}{4}\cos (x)} \right|^2 dx} \left| {\int_0^{\pi /2} {(f(y) - g(y))dy} } \right|^2  \le \int_0^{\pi /2} {\left| {\frac{1}{4}\cos (x)} \right|^2 dx\frac{\pi }{2}\left| {\int_0^{\pi /2} {(f(y) - g(y))^2 dy} } \right|}  = \frac{\pi ^2 }{128}\left\| {f(x) - g(x)} \right\|_2^2 .
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f \in L^2$ be a solution to this equation and define :
$$a = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\text dx$$

The equation is equivalent to $f(x) = x+a\cos(x)$. Using this, we can compute :
$$a = \frac 14 \int_0^{\pi/2} (x+a\cos(x))\text dx =\frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{\pi^2}{8} + a\right)$$

which in turns implies $a = \frac{\pi^2}{24}$.

We have proved that any solution $f$ satisfies $f(x) = x + \frac{\pi^2}{24}\cos(x)$, ie the solution is unique.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. Thanks!!